# Number Of Solutions Of Homogeneous And Non-Homogeneous System

Tags: linear-algebra

let there be a matrix $A^{n*m}$ that $Ax=b$

the solution set of the homogeneous system  $H=(h\in F^m; Ah=0)$ 

the solution set of the non-homogeneous system $L=(l \in F^m; Al=b)$

How do |L| and |H| correlate?

Because $L=l_1+H \rightarrow |L|<|H|$

How can I prove that if $L \neq \emptyset \rightarrow |L|=|H|$?

(Update: Can you please answer without affine space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$H$ is an vectoriel space
$L$ is an afine space which direction is $H$

If $L \neq \emptyset$ there is a solution $x$ to $Al=b$ that means that $L=(l \text{ such as }l=x+h \text{ for } h\in H)$
There you can see that $|H|=|L|$

Without affine space :
We suppose that $L \neq \emptyset$ so there is a solution $x$ to $Al=b$
For each $h \in H$, $A(x+h)=Ax + Ah = b + 0 = b$ so $x+h\in L$. Thus $|H| \le |L|$
For each $l \in L$, $b=Al=A(l-x+x)=A(l-x)+Ax=A(l+x)+b$ so $A(l+x)=0$ so $l+x\in H$. Thus $|L| \le |H|$
In conclusion $|L|=|H|$

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question can you please answer without affine space

Comment: Yeah just saw that. Will try.
But why you don't want affine space? You don't know? This is part of a course where affine space isn't not part of? Or what? Cause with that is, I think, quicker.

Comment: Yes I do not have it in the course, I will read about it, but it is not in my course syllabus at all

Comment: Is that ok now?

Comment: Great, now I got it, but what if |L|=1 and l=x?

Comment: If $|L| = 1$ there is one only solution. So if $x$ is a solution yeah, $l=x$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $L \neq \emptyset$, and fix any reference element $\ell_0 \in L$. Then, the translation map $L \to H$ defined by $\ell \mapsto \ell - \ell_0$ is a bijection.

**Remark** Of course, you'll get different maps for different choices of $\ell_0$. This sort of thinking motivates the slogan that "an affine space is a vector space that has forgotten its origin"---any choice of element $\ell_0$ in an affine space $L$ can be thought of as making a choice of origin and identify $L$ with a vector space $H$.

Comment: why $Ker(T)=0$?

Comment: The kernel of the map is $\{\ell_0\}$, and the map is injective because it's a translation in $F^m$, or if you prefer because it has an inverse given by adding $\ell_0$ back.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question can you please answer without affine space

Comment: My answer is really just the first paragraph (which doesn't reference affine spaces). The remark just contains some information about how this is related to another idea, but you can safely ignore it.